# Checkbox status update working only when checkbox is checked in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I have been working on a project related to restaurant where both super admin and the restaurant owner can update restaurant profile. Restaurant owner & admin has almost fields are same & few are differents.

My problem is that there is one common field which is selecting some food types from some no. of checkboxes. When admin changes checkboxes status it reflect perfectly in the restaurant owner section. However when restaurant owner changes checkboxes status it works but only when restaurant owner check the checkboxes, if the owner uncheck the checkbox it doesn't update. Means owner can't able to uncheck the food type status.

I don't know what is happening why its only updating when restaurant owner check any checkbox not when owner uncheck any checkbox. Super admin side working everything correctly.

Let me know how to solve this problem.

Code I am using for fetching checkboxes, this is not complete code .. its only for checkbox only

```
<?php
$j=0;

  $query="SELECT * FROM cuisine ORDER BY name ASC";
  $rs=mysql_query($query);
  while($rs1=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
  {
   $qid=$rs1["id"];
   $qname=$rs1["name"];
   $j=$j+1;

  ?>
  <td width="200" class="style1"><input 
  <?php  $emprolequery="select count(id) as jj from restuarantcuisine where resid='$resid' and cuisineid='$qid' ";
         $emprolers=mysql_query($emprolequery) or die(mysql_error());
  while($emprolers1=mysql_fetch_array($emprolers))
  { 
  $yes=$emprolers1["jj"];
  }
  if($yes>0)
  {
  ?> checked="checked"
  <?php } ?>
  type="checkbox" name="chkq[]"  value="<?php echo $qid; ?>" /><?php echo $qname; ?> </td>
  <?php

     if($j%2==0 && $j!=0)
  {
  ?>
  </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
  <?php }
   }?>
```

Below code is for receiving the details from the above code...

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include("admin/conn.php");
$resid=$_REQUEST['id'];
$txtname=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtname']);

$txtemail=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtemail']);

$txtwebsite=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtwebsite']);
$txtphone=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtphone']);
$txtcellphone=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtcellphone']);
$provider=ltrim($_REQUEST['provider']);
$restaurantemail=ltrim($_REQUEST['restaurantemail']);
$txtaddress=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtaddress']);
$txtcity=strtoupper($_REQUEST['txtcity']);
$txthours=ltrim($_REQUEST['txthours']);
$txtlogo=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtlogo']);
$txtspecialcode=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtspecialcode']);
$txtdescription=addslashes($_REQUEST['txtdescription']);
$rddelivery=ltrim($_REQUEST['rddelivery']);
$delivery_fee="0";
if($rddelivery=='Y')
    $delivery_fee=ltrim($_REQUEST['delivery_fee']);
$rdrescall=ltrim($_REQUEST['rdrescall']);
$txtmenu=ltrim($_REQUEST['txtmenu']);
$time1=ltrim($_REQUEST['time1']);
$time2=ltrim($_REQUEST['time2']);
$time3=ltrim($_REQUEST['time3']);
$time4=ltrim($_REQUEST['time4']);
$time5=ltrim($_REQUEST['time5']);
$time6=ltrim($_REQUEST['time6']);
$time7=ltrim($_REQUEST['time7']);

$time11=ltrim($_REQUEST['time11']);
$time22=ltrim($_REQUEST['time22']);
$time33=ltrim($_REQUEST['time33']);
$time44=ltrim($_REQUEST['time44']);
$time55=ltrim($_REQUEST['time55']);
$time66=ltrim($_REQUEST['time66']);
$time77=ltrim($_REQUEST['time77']);


if($_FILES['txtlogo']['name'])
{
$fileimage=$_FILES['txtlogo']['name'];

$ext=substr(strrchr($fileimage,'.'),1);
$rander=rand();
$logoimage=$rander.".".$ext;
$path="logo/".$logoimage;
copy($_FILES['txtlogo']['tmp_name'],$path);
$query="update restuarant set logo='$logoimage' where id='$resid'";
mysql_query($query);
}

if($_FILES['txtmenu']['name'])
{
$fileimage=$_FILES['txtmenu']['name'];

$ext=substr(strrchr($fileimage,'.'),1);
$rander=rand();
$menuimage=$rander.".".$ext;
$path="menu/".$menuimage;
copy($_FILES['txtmenu']['tmp_name'],$path);
$query="update restuarant set menu='$menuimage' where id='$resid'";
mysql_query($query);
}
$query="update  restuarant set name='$txtname',address='$txtaddress', phone='$txtphone',cellphone='$txtcellphone',provider='$provider',restaurantemail='$restaurantemail',email='$txtemail', website='$txtwebsite', city='$txtcity',
description='$txtdescription', delivery='$rddelivery',delivery_fee='$delivery_fee', resorcall='$rdrescall', time1='$time1', time2='$time2', time3='$time3', time4='$time4', time5='$time5', time6='$time6', time7='$time7', time11='$time11', time22='$time22', time33='$time33', time44='$time44', time55='$time55', time66='$time66', time77='$time77' where id='$resid'";
//die($query);
//echo $query;
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$restuarantid=mysql_insert_id();
$box[]=$_REQUEST['chkq'];


foreach ($box as $key => $value)
{
foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1)
{

$rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `restuarantcuisine` ( `resid`, `cuisineid`) VALUES (  '$resid','$value1' );");
}
}
header("Location:restprofile_edit.php?flag=true");


?>
```

I am not the original coder of this website .. this is someone else code which I am updating and fixing some issues ...  if I am not using correct approach for this then how I am able to changed the checkbox status as per my need in super admin section.

Comment: Where is the code...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox fields are only present in the post array if they are checked. Your php code must account for this.

Let's assume the name of your checkbox is food1 and the value is 1.
If it is checked, `$_POST['food1']` is `'1'`.
If it is not checked `$_POST['food1']` is not defined.

If your php code relies on `$_POST['food1']` to exist, you get the problem you describe.

Since you didn't show your code, this is a educated guess only.

---

This code is flawed:

```
$box[]=$_REQUEST['chkq'];
foreach ($box as $key => $value)
```

Like I said, a checkbox that is not checked will not be submitted. Therefore `$box` will only contain the values of checked checkboxes, but never of those that are not checked.

In order to get your code work, you must get the list of present checkboxes from your database, and then compare to `$box` to remove unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: I am not using any POST or GET method for checkboxes .. check details above below User016 comment.

Comment: You didn't post the relevant code. You have to post the code where the data gets updated on the server, not the one that created the checkboxes. Your code does not show neither how the form is submitted, nor how the changes are updated through ajax.

Comment: Thanks @Lorenz I examined the code very thoroughly and I have corrected it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if checkbox is posted , if not set it to zero 
for example

```
$checkbox = ($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : 0;
```

because if user didn't check checkbox it didn't sent through POST array

Comment: I am using sessions for checkbox status. only other fields are posted using $_REQUEST method

Comment: check the code above .. and I using only session_start(); function all above the code... if you want to see complete code then let me know

Comment: what i need is when you put to session ? you put it like that
$_SESSION['check'] = $_REQUEST['chkq'];

Comment: can you help me to fix this..I am not an expert in PHP and this is someone else project which I am updating and solving some issue, please check the code in the question

Comment: @VikasKhunteta You did not chose the right approach. A checkbox state change on the client can **NEVER EVER** change your session data on the server. You need either to post your form or have a event handler that sends an ajax update request to the server.

Comment: if this approach is not good then how it is working under admin panel...  can you tell me  @LorenzMeyer

Comment: It's up to you to tell us. Since you pasted your code since I answered you, I update my answer.